# How to use assert in c dll

Tags: c#, c, dll, assert

I am using a legacy C Dll (I have the source code) that has numerous asserts scattered through the program.  The dll is being used by a C# windows app.

The problem is that the "assertion failure" never shows up when there is an error in the DLL.  The Dll is a console app (not sure if that's relevant).   There are dozens of asserts, and AFAIK there is no easy way to get the error mesg (or flag) back to the C# app without adding a lot of extra code.

Is there a way to force the output of the assert to the screen?

Comment: Do you have a debug or release build of the dll?

Comment: Both.  I have the source code, so can build either one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the definition of the `assert()` macro in your C library. It usually has a 'pluggable' output mechanism. Worst case you have to rewrite `assert()` yourself.

The underlying problem here would be that a Console program has **2** output streams: normal and error. The `System.Diagnostics.Process` class has a `StandardError` property that can be used to intercept message written to the `stderror` stream.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the defining NDEBUG turns off the assert mechanism. That identifier is defined per default in release-builds (/D-option). Check if the asserts work in the debug build of your dll and if so, edit your release-project settings to remove the /D option or any NDEBUG-definitions.

Comment: The DLL is a console app, called by a Windows C# app.  So all console output is lost.  The asserts are being hit; that is not the problem.  The problem is that the console output never shows up due to C# app being in control.